# Do LINQ IEnumerable extensions call Dispose on their IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given I've written a class that implements `IEnumerable`, and returns an `IEnumerator` that's not just `IDisposable` by nature of being an enumerator, but from having managed resources that it needs to `Dispose()` after it's done enumerating, can I trust that the following will `Dispose()` those managed resources as long as my enumerator properly disposes those managed resources in its `IDisposable` implementation?

```
return (new MyClass()).Select(x => x);
```

EDIT: This question is seemingly similar to the one mods marked similar to it, but it's semantically different IMO (I saw it before I made the question)

Comment: You need not to about dispose as by John Skeet reply ....[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459447/do-i-need-to-consider-disposing-of-any-ienumerablet-i-use

Comment: If you want to be sure, you could always put a `Console.WriteLine()` in your `Dispose()` and see if it gets fired.

Comment: If his `MyClass` implements `IDisposable` the `Dispose()` method would get called. The garbage collector isn't the one that calls `Dispose()`.

Comment: @MattRowland - That's not right about `MyClass`. In the OP's code `.Dispose` **would not** be called on the `new MyClass()`.

Comment: I wasn't saying that it would. I was saying that he could check to see if it would by placing a `Console.WriteLine()` in the `Dispose()` method.

Comment: I checked of course for this single method, but I wanted to know if this is something I could assume for any LINQ enumeration. Matt is right in that `Dispose()` isn't called from garbage collection. Hence, "managed resources"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on the call of `Dispose()` on your iterators from inside the methods of LINQ.

In the [reference code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e2d8014ab698cbfc) published by Microsoft, the use of iterators falls in three categories:

- Iterators are used from within a `foreach` loop, which ensures a call of `Dispose()`, or
- Iterators are used in conjunction with a `while` loop; these iterators are disposed explicitly
- Iterators are obtained inside a `using` block, which ensures automatic disposal.

In all these cases the library ensures that iterator's `Dispose()` method is called upon completion.

Comment: So *only* in the case of `foreach` is Dispose called automatically 'on enumeration'?

Comment: @user2864740 Yes. If you use `Iterator<T>` manually from inside a `for` or a `while`, you should call `Dispose()` yourself.