# Pipeline pattern and disposable objects

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, pipeline

Recently I started to investigate a `Pipeline` pattern or also known as `Pipes and Filters`. I thought it is a good way to structure the code and applications which just process the data. 
I used this [article](https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2016/10/03/an-alternative-approach-to-pipelines/) as a base for my pipeline and steps implementation (but this is not so important).
As usual blog is covering simple scenario but in my case I need (or maybe not) to work on `IDisposable` objects which might travel through the process.

For instance Streams

Let's consider simple pipeline which should load csv file and insert its rows into some db. In simple abstraction we could implement such functions

```
Stream Step1(string filePath)
IEnumerable<RowType> Step2(Stream stream)
bool Step3(IEnumerable<RowType> data)
```

Now my question is if that is a good approach. Because if we implement that as step after step processing the `Stream` object leaves first step and it is easy to fall into a memory leakage problem.
I know that some might say that I should have `Step1` which is loading and deserialising data but we are considering simple process. We might have more complex ones where passing a Stream makes more sense.

I am wondering how can I implement such pipelines to avoid memory leaks and also avoiding loading whole file into `MemoryStream` (which would be safer). Should I somehow wrap each step in `try..catch` blocks to call `Dispose()` if something goes wrong? Or should I pass all `IDisposable` resources into `Pipeline` object which will be wrapped with `using` to dispose all resources produced during processing correctly?

Comment: It might be worth reconsidering whether the pattern is useful in this scenario. You can write this to deserialize the data into a collection, and then insert the items into a database. Those are two classes. You invoke them both, one after the other. Even if I was using some sort of pipeline I'd still isolate them and call them from the pipeline steps. So that raises the question - what does arranging them in a pipeline add in this case? It seems like we could arrange any sequential steps in pipelines, but should we?

Comment: @ScottHannen basically if I will use the pattern it will be easier to communicate with rest of the team - each member has different experience. So it is a big advantage of  preparing few interfaces and saying to the team 'we should do that with pipeline pattern'. Then it is easy to design steps and share work between developers. I totally agree with you. If I would do it in side project then I don't mind.

Comment: Sharing work though interfaces is awesome, but you don't need a pipeline to do that. It might even make the intent less clear. You could define two abstractions as interfaces: One deserializes, and the other writes to the database. The application depends on both of those abstractions. And then different developers can work on their implementations.

Answer (score 1):

If it's planned to be used like `Step3( Step2( Step1(filePath) ) )`, then 
`Step2` should dispose the stream. It may use `yield return` feature of c#, which creates an implementation of [IEnumerator<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1?view=netframework-4.8) underneath, which implements `IDisposable`, and allows for "subscribing" for the "event" of the finishing of enumerating and call `Stream.Dispose` at that point. E.g. :

```
IEnumerable<RowType> Step2(Stream stream)
{
    using(stream)
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
           yield return Parse(sr.ReadLine()); //yield return implements IEnumerator<>
        }
    } // finally part of the using will be called from IEnumerator<>.Dispose()        
}
```

Then if `Step3` either uses `LINQ`

```
bool Step3(IEnumerable<RowType> data) => data.Any(item => SomeDecisionLogic(item));
```

or `foreach`

```
bool Step3(IEnumerable<RowType> data)
{
    foreach(var item in data)
        if(SomeDecisionLogic(item)))
            return true;
}
```

for enumerating, both of them guarantee to call `IEnumerator<>.Dispose()`  ([ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931596/do-linq-ienumerable-extensions-call-dispose-on-their-ienumerable), [ECMA-334 C# Spec, ch.13.9.5](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf#page=255) ), which will call `Stream.Dispose`

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it is not a problem to pass stream outside of a step - we just need to make sure we don't forget to dispose it in any scenario

Comment: Yes, and `foreach` / `LINQ` methods automatically call `Dispose` on `IEnumerator<>`

Answer (score 1):

IMO it's worth having a pipeline if the interaction is between at least 2 different systems and if the work can be executed in parallel. Otherwise it's more overhead.

In this case there are 2 systems: the file system where the CSV file is and the database. I think the pipeline should have at least 2 steps that run in parallel:

```
IEnumerable<Row> ReadFromCsv(string csvFilePath)
void UpdateDabase<IEnumerable<Row> rows)
```

In this case it should be clear that the Stream is bound to `ReadFromCsv`.

```
IEnumerable<Row> ReadFromCsv(path)
{
  using(var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
  {
      var lines = GetLines(stream); // yield one at a time, not all at once
      foreach (var line in line) yield return GetRow(line);
  }
}
```

I guess the scope depends on the steps - which in turn depend on the way you design the pipeline based on your needs.

Comment: Also have a look at [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library). I have not used it, so my answer may be totally off when compared to this.

Comment: Thanks. As I said earlier. I feel that using a pattern for such processes helps the team to communicate better and share the work. Your point of view is very helpful