# LINQ isn't calling Dispose on my IEnumerator when using Union and Select, expected behavior or bug?

Tags: c#, linq

My understanding is that LINQ IEnumerable extensions are supposed to call Dispose on the IEnumerators produced by the IEnumerable. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931596/do-linq-ienumerable-extensions-call-dispose-on-their-ienumerable). However, I'm not seeing that in practice. Is the other SO answer incorrect, or have I found a bug in LINQ?

Here's a minimal [reproduction](https://repl.it/repls/AquamarineDecisiveVideogame) of the issue using Mono. It also reproduces in Dotnet Core 2.1 & 2.2.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;


namespace union
{
    class MyEnumerable : IEnumerable<long>
    {
        public IEnumerator<long> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new MyEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator<long>
    {
        public long Current
        {
            get
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return Current;
            }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return false;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            return;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I got disposed");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var enum1 = new MyEnumerable();
            var enum2 = new MyEnumerable();

            enum1.Union(enum2).Select(x => x + 1).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("All done!");
        }
    }
}
```

If the Dispose was getting called you would see `I got disposed` twice on the console. Instead you get no `I got disposed`s. The `Union` and the `Select` are required to reproduce the issue.

Any C# gurus know if I've hit a bug?

**Update:**

I believe this is a bug, and I've filed: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40384.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tested in [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), which allows you to use one of three compilers, and the results confirm what you found:

- [.NET 4.7.2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BrHI9N) does dispose
- [Roslyn 2.0](https://dotnetfiddle.net/STB1pl) does dispose
- [.NET Core 2.2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VRdn77) does not

Seems like Mono doesn't either.

But I think I narrowed down what's going on: **It does not call `Dispose()` when the first call to `MoveNext()` returns `false` (i.e. there are no items in the collection).**

You will see this, for example, if you replace your `MoveNext()` code with this, which just returns `true` the first time and `false` thereafter (i.e. simulates a collection with 1 item):

```
private bool happenedOnce = false;
public bool MoveNext()
{
    if (happenedOnce) return false;
    happenedOnce = true;
    return true;
}
```

Here is that example in [Mono](https://repl.it/repls/GoodFondApplication) and [.NET Core 2.2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SNua2j).

I guess it could be argued that it's not a bug, it's a feature. What's there to dispose if there's nothing in the collection? (Scratch that - files and such...)

But then again, it is inconsistent. For example, this will give you exactly the same results, but it *will* dispose, even if there is nothing in the collection:

```
enum1.Select(x => x + 1).Union(enum2.Select(x => x + 1)).ToList();
```

But all that does is force it to iterate the collection using `Select()` instead of `Union()`. So that does sound like it's a bug in the implementation of `Union()`.

I had the time today (family is away visiting friends) so I took the time to [debug the .NET Core source](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/debugging-asp-net-core-2-source). I believe the issue is right [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Union.cs#L105):

```
if (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    SetEnumerator(enumerator);
    StoreFirst();
    return true;
}
```

`SetEnumerator()` stores the enumerator in an instance variable. You see it only gets called if `MoveNext()` returns `true`. Later, in [`Dispose()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Union.cs#L45), it only calls `Dispose()` on the iterator if it's not `null`. But since it never got set, it is indeed `null`.

Contrast that with the implementation of [`Select()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Select.cs#L131), which sets its `_enumerator` variable *before* calling `MoveNext()`.

The .NET Framework just relies on `foreach`, as you can see [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,855). Oddly enough, [so does Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/c5b88ec4f323f2bdb7c7d0a595ece28dae66579c/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L879), so I don't know what's up there.

Comment: _"What's there to dispose if there's nothing in the collection?"_ -- I would argue that's up to the `IEnumerator<T>` implementation to decide, not the caller. The caller should still always call `Dispose()`, regardless. For example, the implementation might enumerate lines in a file; even for an empty file, it has to open the file to determine that there are no lines, and the file should still be closed when enumeration is done, even if no lines are returned. Seems to me this is straight up a bug in those implementations (makes me wonder how much of .NET Core came from Mono)

Comment: Yeah, I agree this is likely a bug, and I've filed an issue. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40384

Comment: Beat me to it :) I can add my findings to the issue.